# How to use 'Merge' to combine rows into a single one

Tags: sql-server, merge

Scenario:
I have a simplified version of a result set obtained from a series of complex joins. I have placed the result set in a temporary table. The result set consists of records of activity/activities in a day.

[image: Result Set]

I need to join the 2 rows (***merge activities of a day into a single row***) with similar dates so that the resulting result set would be

[image: desired result set]

I am trying to make this work

```
Merge #temp as target
using #temp as source
on (target.Date = source.Date) and target.Writing is NULL
when matched then
update set target.Writing = source.Writing;
```

but I'm running into this error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

What code modifications can you suggest?

Comment: Where do the desired results come from? How come `(d,d,d,null),(e,e,null,e)` gets collapsed to  `(d,e,d,e)`?

Comment: It sounds like you're breaking a process down into a series of *procedural* steps, and using a temp table as some form of "scratch space" as you refine the data set. Although you can do this, ideally you *don't* break such a process down into a series of steps. You describe the entire result you want using CTEs and/or subqueries such that the entire thing is a single (large) query and then let the optimizer work out how best to produce this result. I.e. let SQL do what it's good at, working with sets.

Comment: @MartinSmith, the desired results come from various tables joined together. Col1 = time in, Col 2 = time out, Col 3 = Activity 1, Col 4 = Activity 2. All activities in a day should be reflected in a single row only

Comment: **Update your question** so that it is clear and contains all necessary information. Comments can disappear.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I haven't used CTEs before. I'll look into that.

Comment: Why was a `d` picked instead of a `e` for `Col 1` where `Date` is `08-04` and why was `e` picked instead of `e` for `Col 2` on the same row?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, please see the updated images.

Comment: Still not clear to me what makes you choose one value over the other. You picked `8:00` over `5:00` for `Time In` because it is greater? Or because `Reading` is `Y` or because `Writing` is blank/null? Or .... ?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson The desired row should show the time the 2 activities occurred. I'm merely keeping the start time for Reading (1st activity), and end time for Writing (2nd activity).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
    SELECT dfl.mydate, dfl.firststart, dfl.lastend, fa.ActivityA, sa.ActivityB 
    FROM
    (select s.mydate, firststart, lastend FROM
    (SELECT mydate, MIN(starttime) as firststart from target GROUP by mydate) s
    iNNER JOIN
    (SELECT mydate, MAX(EndTime) as lastend from target GROUP by mydate) e
    ON s.mydate = e.mydate) AS dfl
    INNER JOIN
    target fa on dfl.mydate = fa.mydate and dfl.firststart = fa.starttime
    INNER JOIN
    target sa on dfl.mydate = sa.mydate and dfl.lastend = sa.EndTime
```

Please note for my test I have called my table target and the columns: mydate, starttime, endtime, activitya and activityb.

No need to merge, a (relatively) simple select yields the results you want.

HTH

PS It helps when using time data to use a 24 hour clock.  I have assumed by 5:00 you really meant 17:00

Answer (score 0):

You don't need MERGE statement.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE ([Id] int, [Date] nvarchar(10), [TimeIn] nvarchar(10), [TimeOut] nvarchar(10), [Reading] nvarchar(10), [Writeing] nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Test 
VALUES
(1,'08-01','8:00','5:00','Y',NULL),
(2,'08-02','8:00','5:00',NULL,'Y'),
(3,'08-02','5:00','12:00',NULL,'Y'),
(4,'08-03','8:00','5:00',NULL,'Y'),
(5,'08-04','1:00','5:00','Y',NULL),
(6,'08-04','5:00','7:00',NULL,'Y'),
(7,'08-04','7:00','10:00',NULL,'Y'),
(8,'08-04','10:00','13:00',NULL,'Y'),
(9,'08-05','8:00','5:00','Y',NULL)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.[Date],
        t1.TimeIn,
        ISNULL(t2.TimeOut, t1.TimeOut) AS TimeOut,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[Date] ORDER BY t1.Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM @Test AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Test AS t2 ON t1.TimeOut = t2.TimeIn AND t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
)
SELECT
    c.[Date],
    (SELECT c2.TimeIn FROM CTE AS c2 WHERE c2.[Date] = c.[Date] AND c2.RowNumber = MIN(c.RowNumber)) AS TimeIn,
    (SELECT c2.TimeOut FROM CTE AS c2 WHERE c2.[Date] = c.[Date] AND c2.RowNumber = MAX(c.RowNumber)) AS TimeOut
FROM CTE AS c
GROUP BY c.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge statements in tables where you have an identical column. You can identify the one or more columns that can be used to uniquely identify the row to be merged.